# python подключение mysql ошибка access denied

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, access

```
import pymysql.cursors

myServer = 'localhost'
myDatabase = 'mainDB'
myUser = 'root'
myPassword = 'root'

link = pymysql.connect( host = myServer,
                        db = myDatabase,
                        user = myUser,
                        password = myPassword)
```

Ошибка:

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")

Такая же ошибка при попытке подключиться через терминал используя это

```
mysql -u root -p
```

но так `sudo mysql -u root -p` проблем нет.

Пытаюсь запустить файл с программой с правами суперпользователя, но ошибка остаётся на месте.

Мозгом понимаю что проблема элементарная и надо просто кому-то каких-то прав дать, но 2 дня уже не могу понять кому и каких именно.

**Ubuntu 18.04**, **mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24**, **Python 3.6.7**

Comment: Непонятно причем тут питон, если ошибка связана с mysql. Попробуйте так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46908573/5909792

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, это решило мою проблему. а python при том, что пока я не пытался взаимодействовать с БД через него у меня не было проблем)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема видимо не связанна с python попробуйте выполнить в терминале  БД эти команды:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='%' WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='имя_пользователя';
UPDATE mysql.db SET Host='%' WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='имя_пользователя';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

(не забудьте поменять `имя_пользователя` на нужное вам)

так же, если это вдруг не поможет, попробуйте ввести это в терминале:

```
systemctl stop mysqld
mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

А затем это в терминале БД:

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('ваш_пароль') where USER='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

В Первом способе, вы разрешаете подключаться к БД с любых IP

во втором же, вы перезапускаете службу mysql без проверки безопасности, и меняете пароль у пользователя `root` на `ваш_пароль` не забудьте сделать удобный вам пароль